# android: how to fix error constructor CardPagerAdapter in class CardsActivity.CardPagerAdapter cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, import

Source code: https://github.com/jamesmccann/android-view-pager-cards/blob/master/app/src/main/java/nz/jamesmccann/cardviewpager/CardActivity.java
i downloaded it and it doesn't worked, so i copied in my project. but some error happened and i don't know how to fix although i search many times.
This is CarContainerFragment:

```
 import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class CardContainerFragment extends Fragment {

    private boolean cardFlipped = false;

    public CardContainerFragment() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentcardcontainer, container, false);

        getChildFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new CardFrontFragment())
                .commit();

        return rootView;
    }

    public void flipCard() {
        Fragment newFragment;
        if (cardFlipped) {
            newFragment = new CardFrontFragment();
        } else {
            newFragment = new CardBackFragment();
        }

        getChildFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(
                        R.anim.card_flip_right_in, R.anim.card_flip_right_out,
                        R.anim.card_flip_left_in, R.anim.card_flip_left_out)
                .replace(R.id.container, newFragment)
                .commit();

        cardFlipped = !cardFlipped;
    }

    public static class CardFrontFragment extends Fragment {

        public CardFrontFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentcard, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class CardBackFragment extends Fragment {

        public CardBackFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_back, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

This is CardsActivity:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class CardsActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitycard);

        CardPagerAdapter adapter = new CardPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class CardPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public CardPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new Fragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

This is error that i gotten:

```
  Error:(24, 36) error: constructor CardPagerAdapter in class CardsActivity.CardPagerAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
found: android.app.FragmentManager
reason: actual argument android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager by method invocation conversion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours `CardsActivity` has different imports than the one on the github link.

**Yours**:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

**Github**:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

In my opinion you should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` not `getFragmentManager()` (you have to extend from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` instead from `Activity` to get this method).

Comment: I dont't see getSupportFragmentManager() althought I added android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.

Comment: It's here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager() just extend your activity class 'public class CardsActivity extends FragmentActivity {'